# GCC and Crypto++ on makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, crypto++

I'm trying to compile C++ project with gcc-make command but program giving this error. I already compiled Crypto++ and added include and lib folder but I dont know how to add this dir to gcc.

What should I do for fixing this "-lcrytopp" error?

I'm using makefile and this is line of 33-34.

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET) -lcryptopp
```

**Error**:

```
D:\Osman\CnC RA2\Mix\ccmix-crypto\ccmix-crypto>make
g++ src/mix_db_gamedb.o src/mix_db_gmd.o src/mix_header.o src/mix_db_lmd.o
src/mixid.o src/ccmix.o src/mix_file.o -o build/ccmix -lcryptopp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32
/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcryptopp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'build/ccmix' failed
make: *** [build/ccmix] Error 1
```

---

Crypto++ directory:

[image]

Compile error:

[image]

Comment: please include the error in the question

Comment: Im added error.Sorry for wrong picture.

Comment: Please add the error and a [mcve] of your makefile and code to the question **as text**.

Comment: I'm added 2 line of makefile. Because program giving error in line 34. make command can't find crytopp directory and /include , /lib subdirs.

Comment: As mentioned, you should cut and paste the actual text of the error into the question, not add a picture of the error.

Comment: ah, okey Im added error. I hope do right this time.

Comment: @OsmanBaturÇelik - I rolled back your edits. Please ask one question so you can get complete answers. Don't make the question a moving target. The previous answers may become irrelevant or not make sense. If needed, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the directory containing the library to your link line.  It should be something like `-Lxxx` where `xxx` is the path to the directory containing the `cryptopp` library:

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET) -Lxxx -lcryptopp
```

(replace `xxx` with the directory containing the `cryptopp` library)

Comment: I added                                                                                                    `$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
 $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET) -LC:\cryptopp\include\cryptopp -lcryptopp` but still giving same error about -lcrytopp

Comment: I doubt that the library is in a directory named `include`.  Do you see `cryptopp.lib` in the directory you added to the link line?

Comment: Yes sir, I fix this probleam with rename crytlib.lib to crypto.lib but this time giving `src/mix_file.o: In function `ZN8CryptoPP31IteratedHashWithStaticTransformIjNS_10EnumToTypeINS_9ByteOrderELi1EEELj64ELj20ENS_4SHA1ELj0ELb0EE24HashEndianCorrectedBlockEPKj':
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/include/cryptopp/iterhash.h:170: undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SHA1::Transform(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'build/ccmix' failed
make: *** [build/ccmix] Error 1`

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do for fixing this "-lcrytopp" error?

When working from the Crypto++ build directory on Unix compatibles, the project does not use `include` and `lib` (as your picture shows). Everything is placed in the root directory (as your picture shows).

If you perform a `make install`, then the directories are setup, but it appears you did not install. I should also say that MinGW is not usually tested anymore because the project is abandoned, so I'm not sure where `make install` actually installs to on MinGW.

To fix the compile error, tweak your make recipe:

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I. $(OBJECTS) ./libcryptopp.a -o $(TARGET)
```

The recipe above uses `CXX` (C++ compiler) rather than `CC` (C compiler); it uses `CXXFLAGS` (which should be something like `-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2`); it calls out the header path (`-I.`); and it links to the static library (`./libcryptopp.a`). Linking to the static library will avoid your next set of problems.

You can follow MadScientist's advice and use `-LXXX` and `-lcryptopp`. You might even add a runpath with `-Wl,-rpath,D:\Osman\CnC RA2\Mix\ccmix-crypto\ccmix-crypto`. But at the end of the day, using `-L` and `-l` causes a fair amount of trouble. Avoid the future problems by statically linking `libcryptopp.a`.

Also see [GNUmakefile | Compiling and Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GNUmakefile#Compiling_and_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

Your fist picture shows `ipch` and `Win32` directories. That usually means you built the Crypto++ library with Visual Studio. Now you are building a program with GCC. You ***should not*** mix and match compilers like that. Nothing good will come of it.